# How to fill null values in a Pyspark Dataframe column with values from the same column, whose corresponding value in another column is same

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have below data:

df=

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | abc |
| 102 | def |
| **null** | ghi |
| 104 | ghi |
| **null** | abc |
| 104 | ghi |
| 102 | def |
| 101 | abc |

expected output=

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | abc |
| 102 | def |
| **104** | ghi |
| 104 | ghi |
| **101** | abc |
| 104 | ghi |
| 102 | def |
| 101 | abc |

I tried using the below codes:
code1=

```
df.where(df.user_id.isNotNull()).select("user_id", "user_name").distinct().show()
```

output:

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | abc |
| 102 | def |
| 104 | ghi |

2nd code=

```
df.filter(F.col("user_id").isNull()).withColumn("user_id", F.when(df.user_id.isNull(), "a")).show()
```

output:

| user_id | user_name | dep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | ghi | test |
| a | abc | dev |

I need to somehow use this both code lines in 1 single code, so that the "a" can be updated and I get the desired output. Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the `code1` to original dataframe and use `coalesce` to fill the value. `coalesce` takes the first non-null values in either column.

```
# I add renaming of column to avoid the duplicate column name.
code1 = (df.where(df.user_id.isNotNull())
        .select("user_id", "user_name")
        .withColumnRenamed("user_id", "fill_user_id")
        .distinct())

# Join with original dataframe and fill the value
df = (df.join(code1, on="user_name", how="left")
     .select(F.coalesce("user_id", "fill_user_id").alias("user_id"), "user_name"))
```

Result

```
+-------+---------+
|user_id|user_name|
+-------+---------+
|    104|      ghi|
|    104|      ghi|
|    104|      ghi|
|    101|      abc|
|    101|      abc|
|    101|      abc|
|    102|      def|
|    102|      def|
+-------+---------+
```

An alternative solution is to use Window function to fill. With Window function, you can fill missing values with just 1 function. I use `first` with `ignorenulls=True` option to take first non-null value with the same user_name.

```
df = df.withColumn("user_id", 
         F.first("user_id", ignorenulls=True).over(Window.partitionBy("user_name")))
```

Comment: Thank you, I liked the window function approach. One qs I need to ask you, how do we develop intuition like this when solving problems?

Comment: If your operation depending on other rows whether aggregating other rows or taking values from other rows, you probably have a luck with some Window functions. I recommend looking up "Window function in Pyspark" to check more variations of the window functions.